# permission denied error while building/checking R package on WIndows

Tags: r, windows, package-development

I tried to build the R package `hyperSpec` using Windows Vista. When I do so, I get the following error message:

```
warning in file.copy(pkgname, Tdir, recursive = TRUE)
Problem copying .\hyperSpec\data\barbiturates.rda to C:\Users\JenZIG\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOEIqBD\Rbuilde446d3a290d\hyperSpec\data\barbiturates.rda: Permission denied
```

It is all the same whether I use the command line with `R CMD build` or R Studio's Build Tools (RTools installed, all package dependencies installed).

To solve the problem, I tried to change the path for the temporary directory or to manually set the permissions for the folders but without success. I tried to execute everything as administrator but again no success.

I think, a similar problem was discussed here:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2013-April/066389.html

However, there is no solution provided for this problem.

In addition, I have the same problem when I try to build the package with Win7.

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem. I had previously installed the package in question using the command line:

```
sudo R -e "install.packages('somepackage', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
```

Then when I tried building the `somepackage` package from source I got the *permission denied* message.

The solution was to run the following from the command line:

```
sudo R -e "remove.packages('somepackage')"
```

Then I was able to build and check `somepackage` from source.

**EDIT**

I see that the original question was specific to Windows. In that case I think you simply need to run a powershell window as administrator and use the following command:

```
Rscript.exe "remove.packages('somepackage')"
```

Comment: I have experienced this problem intermittently (for a different R package which had to be built from source on Windows because it was not available as a binary from CRAN).  I have been unable to discover what causes it (although since the link in the question suggests it is related to the need for administrator privileges, I will look into that next time it occurs).  My *solution* has been to manually cleanup all old files from prior failed install attempts (ie delete /src-i386, /src-x64, and "R library"/"package-name", and try the install again - which (thus far) has worked for me.

Comment: I think it should be `Rscript.exe -e "remove.packages('somepackage')"` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was unloading the package, removing the package, restarting R Studio, and then reinstalling it.

(in R Studio on the right hand side of the interface there is a tab called "Packages" that lets you do all of these things)