# Installing "e1071"

Tags: r

I have been trying to install R package 'e1071' but been receiving error message

> **Error**:  in install.packages : cannot open file
>   'C:/Users/Elikplim/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/filecf8349c707f/numDeriv/doc/Guide.pdf':
>   Permission denied.

any suggestions?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: from the path and drive letter I guess its windows, have you seen response to [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471789/permission-denied-error-while-building-checking-r-package-on-windows)

Comment: @elikplim Did you start R with administrator privileges? `install.packages()` doesn't work well unless you're running R as administrator.